Error parsing CSV file: [TypeError: Network request failed]
I am using papaparse to implement a csv file in my react native application. I cant figure out why I keep getting this error that states Error parsing CSV file: [TypeError: Network request failed].
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Papa from 'papaparse';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      answers: {},
      csvData: []
    };

    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.parseCSV();
  }

  async parseCSV() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('./assets/data.csv');
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
      const result = await reader.read();
      const csvData = decoder.decode(result.value);

      Papa.parse(csvData, {
        header: true,
        complete: this.getData
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing CSV file:', error);
    }
  }

  getData(result) {
    this.setState({ csvData: result.data });
  }


Make sure your url is correct.

Do you really need for it to be CSV?
If not, you can convert it to json with something like https://csvjson.com/csv2json
And use it as json file
If you specifically want CSV file use something like react-native-fs package, it handles local files work in react native
